# jq filter to aggregate into an object's property

Tags: json, group-by, aggregate, jq

I need to transform JSON to update a firebase firestore.

My incoming json looks like this:

```
[{
    "ItemID": 1,
    "Size": 10,
    "Price": 5
},
{
    "ItemID": 1,
    "Size": 11,
    "Price": 7
},
{
    "ItemID": 1,
    "Size": 12,
    "Price": 10
},
{
    "ItemID": 2,
    "Size": 11,
    "Price": 15
},
{
    "ItemID": 2,
    "Size": 12,
    "Price": 20
}]
```

And I need JSON to look like this:

```
[{
    "ItemID": 1,
    "Price": {
        "10": 5,
        "11": 7,
        "12": 10
    }
},
{
    "ItemID": 2,
    "Price": {
        "11": 15,
        "12": 20
    }
}]
```

What jq filter do I need to do that please?

My other alternatives are to loop through it in javascript, however I want to make this extendable so the pattern can be added, saved and run.

My other alternative is not to store values as keys, to do something like:

```
[
  {
    "ItemID":1,
    "Prices":[
      {"Size":10, "Price":5}
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Please fix the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fixing the JSON, the following filter produces the output as shown below:

```
group_by(.ItemID)
| map( reduce .[] as $x ( .[0] | {ItemID};
         .Price += ($x | {(.Size|tostring): .Price}) ) )
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "ItemID": 1,
    "Price": {
      "10": 5,
      "11": 7,
      "12": 10
    }
  },
  {
    "ItemID": 2,
    "Price": {
      "11": 15,
      "12": 20
    }
  }
]
```